# Django Admin interface with pickled set

Tags: python, django, user-interface, django-admin

I have a model that has a pickled set of strings. (It has to be pickled, because Django has no built in set field, right?)

```
class Foo(models.Model):

    __bar = models.TextField(default=lambda: cPickle.dumps(set()), primary_key=True)

    def get_bar(self):
        return cPickle.loads(str(self.__bar))

    def set_bar(self, values):
        self.__bar = cPickle.dumps(values)

    bar = property(get_bar, set_bar)
```

I would like the set to be editable in the admin interface. Obviously the user won't be working with the pickled string directly. Also, the interface would need a widget for adding/removing strings from a set.

What is the best way to go about doing this? I'm not super familiar with Django's admin system. Do I need to build a custom admin widget or something?

**Update**: If I do need a custom widget, this looks helpful: http://www.fictitiousnonsense.com/archives/22

**Update 2**: Now I'm looking through different relational models to see if that will work. One idea I'm toying with:

```
class FooMember(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
      foo = models.ForeignKey('Foo')

class Foo(models.Model):
      def get_names(self):
          return FooMember.objects.filter(foo__exact=self)
```

Disadvantages of this include:

- It feels excessive to make an entire model for one data field (`name`).
- I would like the admin interface for `Foo` to allow the user to enter a list of strings. I'm not sure how to do that with this setup; making a custom form widget seems like less work.

Comment: A ManyToManyField is similar to a set.  Could you make your strings `unique=True` fields in another model, and include a ManyToManyField of that model in Foo?

Comment: "It feels excessive to make an entire model for one data field (name)" --- it does feel this way, but those are just rows in a database table.

Answer (score 2):

Uhm. Django usually stores it's data in an SQL database. Storing a set as a pickled string is definietly not the best way to use an SQL database. It's not immediately obvious which is the right solution in your case, that depends what is in that set, but this is the wrong solution in any case.

You might want a new table for that set, or at least save it as comma separated values or something.

Comment: Can you explain why it's the wrong approach? The set will never have more than ~10 items in it, so I don't need fast lookup times. Also, what advantage does CSV have over pickled? (aside from complaining more if the item I'm pickling isn't a set.)

Comment: The advantage of CSV is that you can read it even if you don't have python around. If you want everything in pickles, try ZODB an object oriented database based on pickles that is pretty awesome. It's the wrong approach because it does use the SQL database you have, it's not portable, it's complicated to implement, it's brittle and prone to breaking. There is nothing compelling about it at all.